# Attach files in batches of 7, change Subject & Body accordingly

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The below code attaches one file per email. I need to attach seven files from the folder.

I have approximately 150 files.

I need to

1. In the first email attach the first 7 files and then loop to attach 7 files to each subsequent email then in the last email attach the remaining three PDF files.
2. Subject for the first email: Invoice 001 to Invoice 007
   Body for First Email:
   Please find attached the following invoices
   Invoice 001 to Invoice 007 (7 invoices)
   ...
   Subject for the last email: Invoice 148 to Invoice 150
   Body for last Email:
   Please find attached the following invoices
   Invoice 148 to Invoice 150 (3 invoices)

```vb
Sub sendmailsss()
    
    Dim path As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    
    counter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("I4")
    path = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("M2")
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("M2") = "" Then
        MsgBox "No folder selected. Please Select a folder with Invoives."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    fpath = path & "\*.pdf"
    fname = Dir(path)
    
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim Source As String
    Dim subj() As String
    Do While fname <> ""
        subj = Split(fname, ".")
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
        Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim OutAccount As Outlook.Account
        Set OutAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
    
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        Source = path & fname
        With OutMail
            .To = "info@abc.co.uk"
            .Subject = "Company Ltd " & subj(0)
            .HTMLBody = "Invoice attached"
            .Attachments.Add Source
            .SendUsingAccount = OutAccount
    
            '.Display
            .Send
        End With
        If Err Then
            MsgBox "Error while sending Email" & vbLf & "Press OK to check it in the Outlook", vbExclamation
            '.Display
        Else
            ms = ms + 1
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:10 AM#
    
        fname = Dir()
        'If ms = 3 Then
        '    Exit Do
        'End If
    Loop
    MsgBox "Process Completed. " & ms & " emails sent."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the re-built code:

```
 Sub SendMailSSS()
    
    Dim path As String
    'Dim counter As Integer
    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim outAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim source As String
    'Dim subj() As String
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fileList As Variant
    Dim innerLoop As Integer
    
    Dim fileCounter As Integer
    
    'counter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("I4")
    path = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M2")
    
    If path <> "" Then
    
        fileList = FncGetFilesFromPath(path)
        fileCounter = 0
        
        Do While fileCounter < UBound(fileList)
        
            Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set outAccount = outApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
            Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                
            With outMail
                
                .To = "info@abc.co.uk"
                .Subject = "Company Ltd " & "Whatever 'subj' array was supposed to be doing in your code"
                .HTMLBody = "Invoice attached"
                .SendUsingAccount = outAccount
                        
                'Gets next up to 7 files
                For innerLoop = fileCounter To (fileCounter + 7)
                    
                    If innerLoop <= UBound(fileList) Then
                        
                          .Attachments.Add fileList(innerLoop)
                    
                    Else
                    
                        Exit For
                        
                    End If
                    
                Next innerLoop
            
            End With
            
            outMail.Send
            
            fileCounter = fileCounter + innerLoop
            
        Loop
    
    Else
    
        MsgBox "No folder selected. Please Select a folder with Invoices."
    
    End If
    
    Set outApp = Nothing
    Set outMail = Nothing
    Set outAccount = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Function FncGetFilesFromPath(fPath As String) As Variant

    Dim result As Variant
    Dim fName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ReDim result(0)
    i = 0
    
    fName = Dir(fPath)
    
    Do While fName <> ""
        
        ReDim Preserve result(i)
        result(i) = fPath & fName
        i = i + 1
        
        fName = Dir()
        
    Loop
    
    FncGetFilesFromPath = result
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks
@Davy C
and Eugene
It is emailing now but attaching 8 files instead of 7.
My PDF files are named like
ABC-FEB22-001.PDF
ABC-FEB22-002.PDF
ABC-FEB22-003.PDF
I want to 
Add the subject like (Invoices: ABC-FEB22-001 to ABC-FEB22-007)
Add a delay of 20 seconds before the second email is sent
When the macro is finished a message appears that x number of emails are sent successfully.

Comment: I think your initial post was answered. For any subsequent questions I'd recommend posting separately.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt this into your existing code. What you need to do I think is add all the references to the attachment files to an array first. This will allow you to loop over them according to your specific counting requirements of 7 per e-mail:

```
 Sub SendMailSSS()
    
    Dim path As String
    'Dim counter As Integer
    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim outAccount As Outlook.Account
    Dim source As String
    'Dim subj() As String
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fileList As Variant
    Dim innerLoop As Integer
    
    Dim fileCounter As Integer
    
    'counter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("I4")
    path = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M2")
    
    If path <> "" Then
    
        fileList = FncGetFilesFromPath(path & "\*.pdf")
        fileCounter = 0
        
        Do While fileCounter < UBound(fileList)
        
            Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set outAccount = outApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
            Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                
            With outMail
                
                .To = "info@abc.co.uk"
                .Subject = "Company Ltd " & "Whatever 'subj' array was supposed to be doing in your code"
                .HTMLBody = "Invoice attached"
                .SendUsingAccount = outAccount
                        
                'Gets next up to 7 files
                For innerLoop = fileCounter To (fileCounter + 7)
                    
                    If innerLoop <= UBound(fileList) Then
                        
                          .Attachments.Add fileList(innerLoop)
                    
                    Else
                    
                        Exit For
                        
                    End If
                    
                Next innerLoop
            
            End With
            
            outMail.Send
            
            fileCounter = fileCounter + innerLoop
            
        Loop
    
    Else
    
        MsgBox "No folder selected. Please Select a folder with Invoices."
    
    End If
    
    Set outApp = Nothing
    Set outMail = Nothing
    Set outAccount = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Function FncGetFilesFromPath(fPath As String) As Variant

    Dim result As Variant
    Dim fName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ReDim result(0)
    i = 0
    
    fName = Dir(fPath)
    
    Do While fName <> ""
        
        ReDim Preserve result(i)
        result(i) = fPath & fName
        i = i + 1
        
        fName = Dir()
        
    Loop
    
    FncGetFilesFromPath = result
    
End Function
```

I'm not sure what "subj" or "counter" are supposed to be doing in your code so I have commented them out. I cannot 100% test this, because I don't have Outlook on this machine, but it should give you the idea of how the looping will work.

Comment: Sorry as I am completely new to VBA.
I am a bit confused.
Do I need to replace the old code with the one you have provided?

Comment: On running the macro its giving the error message "Runtime error '-2147024894 (80070002) Cannot find this file. Verify Path and file name are correct. When I press the debug button it takes me to this line of code  .Attachements.Add fileList (innerLoop)

Comment: Type this in the "Immediate" window: DEBUG.PRINT fileList(innerLoop)                ..... is it a valid file? Copy/paste into Windows Explorer and see if it opens a valid file.

Comment: on typing DEBUG.PRINT fileList(innerLoop)
In the immediate window it appears
F:\Invoices\ABC\Revised 22042022\\*.pdfBCC-DEC21-140.pdf

I think this portion" \*.pdf" in the path is causing error.

Comment: You need to remove the extra part from the `FncGetFilesFromPath(path)` line. Check out the fixed code which I've just posted.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Nice one!

Comment: Thanks, @Davy C, 
I will make a separate post for additional requirements,  but it is still attaching 8 files instead of 7.